# listing all years, quarters and quarter dates between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server, date

I have two dates (Date From =`2016-07-09` and Date To=`2018-06-30`). I want to list all the years and quarters numbers like following:

```
Code      No    From        To          Desc
AB-A       1    09-Jul-16   30-Jun-17   Year
AB-A       2    01-Jul-17   31-Jul-18   Year
AB-A       1    09-Jul-16   30-Sep-16   Qtr
AB-A       2    01-Oct-16   31-Dec-16   Qtr
AB-A       3    01-Jan-17   31-Mar-17   Qtr
AB-A       4    01-Apr-17   30-Jun-17   Qtr
AB-A       5    01-Jul-17   30-Sep-17   Qtr
AB-A       6    01-Oct-17   31-Dec-17   Qtr
AB-A       7    01-Jan-18   31-Mar-18   Qtr
AB-A       8    01-Apr-18   30-Jun-18   Qtr
```

I used the following but it gives different result.

```
DECLARE @start date='2016-07-09';
declare @end date = '2018-06-30';

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS No,DateFrom, DateTo,'Qtr' AS Descr FROM (
select distinct year(dateadd(day,rnum,@start)) yr,@start AS DateFrom,@end AS DateTo,
datepart(quarter,dateadd(day,rnum,@start)) periodDesc
from (select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rnum
      from master..spt_values) t
where dateadd(day,rnum,@start) <= @end) as myquery;
```

Comment: Consider building a calendar table of one row per date then these requirements become trivially simple.

Comment: Is correct the values for the last dates of years and quarters? Should they be '2017-06-30'?

Comment: Yes the correct date for the last date should be 2018-06-30.

Comment: Used_By_Already Thank you for the suggestion. That should work to have a separate table to add date but I want this to be automatically create after user inputs the Date From and Date To. Secondly, the quarter period is not fixed. For one party the first quarter may start from Jan but another it may start March first.